# Como realizar el promedio de los elementos de un vector aplicando la recursividad

Tags: array, c

Estoy intentando aprender lenguaje en C y me pidieron que realice el promedio de elementos de un Vector utilizando la recursividad. Pero realmente no tengo mucho conocimiento al respecto. Alguna ayuda?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int vector[4];
    int i;


    for (i=0; i<4; i++){
        printf( "ingrese 4 numeros. Numero %d\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &vector[i]);
    }
    int mayor,menor;
    mayor=vector[0];
    menor= vector[0];
    float promedio;
    int total;

    for (i=0; i<4; i++){
        if (vector[i]> mayor){
            mayor=vector[i];
        }

        if (vector[i]< menor){
            menor=vector[i];
        }

        total+=vector[i];
    }
    printf("El mayor es %d\n", mayor);
    printf("El menor es %d\n", menor);

    promedio = total/4.0;
    printf("El Promedio es:%f\n",promedio);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Estás intentando aprender lenguje C, y te pidieron un ejercicio. Para pedirte ese ejercicio, se supone entonces que ya tendrás algún conocimiento sobre el lenguaje. En éste comunidad no se lleva muy bien que la gente pida que les hagan sus tareas, por eso deberías de mostrar tu interés por aprender, y pegar aquí el código de tus intentos por conseguir realizar el ejercicio, de lo contrario, no obtendrás ninguna respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: Realicé un código esta mañana. más no se como hacer para colocarlo en el foro como hacen los demás; De igual manera, este es

Answer (score 0):

La recursión es una la llamada de una función varias veces, para eso podemos meter esta llamada dentro de tu ciclo `for` y pasarle 2 parámetros.

1. `prom`: será el promedio que llevemos sacando hasta ahora
2. `valor`: será el valor actual en el que estemos dentro del `for`

Para sacar el promedio podemos dividir cada número entre el total, por ejemplo, si tenemos `[4,4,2,6]` y queremos hallar el promedio podemos sumar y dividir entre 4 o dividir entre 4 cada elemento e ir sumando, esto es lo que haremos.

Una cosa es que cambie el nombre de la variable `promedio` a `prom`

```
//funcion para hallar el promedio
float promedio(int prom,int valor){
    return prom+(valor/4);
}
int main(){
    //...
    float prom;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if(vector[i]>mayor){
            mayor=vector[i];
        }else if(vector[i]<menor){ //coloque un else if
            menor = vector[i];
        }
        //llamamos a la funcion
        prom=promedio(prom, vector[1]);
    }
}
```

Si quieres hacerlo sin el ciclo `for` también lo puedes hacer, en este caso se tendría que modificar la función `promedio()` para que se llame a si misma.

```
float promedio(int vector[],int pos){
    if(pos <4 ){ //si la posicion es menor que el tamaño del vector
        return vector[pos]/4.0+promedio(vector,pos+1);//volvemos a llamar a la funcion
    }
}

int main(){
   //...
   for (i=1; i<4; i++){
        if (vector[i]> mayor){
            mayor=vector[i];
        }else if (vector[i]< menor){
            menor=vector[i];
        }
    }
    //...
    prom = promedio(vector,0); //empezamos desde el 0
    printf("El promedio es:%f",prom);
}
```

**resultado**

```
ingrese 4 numeros. Numero 1
4
ingrese 4 numeros. Numero 2
4
ingrese 4 numeros. Numero 3
2
ingrese 4 numeros. Numero 4
6
El mayor es:6
El menor es:2
El Promedio es:4.000000
```

Tambien puedes hacerlo de reversa, es decir pasarle el limite y la condición cambiaría a `if(pos >=0 )` y lo llamarías así `prom = promedio(vector,3);`

Comment: Ok, ya voy captando. Me habían comentado que, para utilizar la recursividad, no es necesario utilizar "for", se puede incluir sin ningún problema?

Comment: claro, pero la función cambiaria un poco

Comment: @RicardoJaimes listo! edite la pregunta añadiendo esa forma

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que estas aprendiendo, pero como mencionaron previamente, nadie deberia resolver toda tu tarea, entonces te voy a dar un ayuda y vos la completas.

Para sumar los numeros de tu arreglo con recursividad, tenes que definir una funcion aparte. Esta funcion debe recibir un arreglo y su tamanio (4 en este caso), o sea que es de la forma `int promedio(arreglo, size)`. Luego, para iterar sobre el arreglo tenes que decrementar la variable `size` en cada "auto llamado" a la funcion "promedio" y a la vez ir sumando sus elementos, o osea `return arreglo[size] + promedio[arreglo, size-1]`. Te dejo a vos definir la condicion de corte de esta recursividad y el calculo final del promedio porque son tareas sumamente sencillas.

Ademas, ya que estas aprendiendo, te recomiendo usar [pythonTutor-C++](http://pythontutor.com/cpp.html#mode=edit) para visualizar paso a paso tus codigos. suerte!

Comment: Okok, muchisimas gracias, yo realizo los códigos con DevC++

Comment: Si, la sintaxis que escribi es generica para que se vea mas clara la idea y no introducir palabras reservadas de c++ que quizas hagan mas larga la explicacion. Espero que te haya servido